# How to disable $ pairing in latex-mode in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, smartparens

When I click $ I get another matching $ thanks to smartparens. I would like to disable this behavior but keep all other matching pairs like () enabled. I tried adding this to the Spacemacs config but it doesn't work:

```
(sp-local-pair 'LaTeX-mode "$" nil :actions :rem)
```

Answer (score 3):

Fun fact: there is `LaTeX-mode`, and then there is `latex-mode`. Both are aliases for `TeX-latex-mode`, which is part of the AUCTeX package. If you look at the default value of `sp-pairs`, you'll see settings for `latex-mode`, not `LaTeX-mode`. The following command disabled `$` pairing for me in LaTex documents:

```
(sp-local-pair #'latex-mode "$" nil :actions nil)
```

(I use `:actions nil` because that is what is recommended by the documentation of `sp-local-pair`)